# Fastlane sigh provisioning profile not installing properly

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, fastlane

We are trying to automate the iOS build process with Jenkins. With sigh we are able to download the profile and it says its installed successfully. But when we open the project in Xcode the installed profile is not showing up. But if we download and install manually from the developer portal then its showing up. Any suggestion on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: What is the command you are running?  I believe unless you specify the output directory, it just downloads the profiles to the current directory.  Have you tried `fastlane sign -o "~/Library/MobileDevices/Provisioning Profiles/"` ?

Comment: Thanks wottle. I specified the directory and its working fine now.

Comment: OK, I'll put it out there as an answer in case anyone in the future finds your question, to make it easier for them to find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the fastlane sigh command without specifying an output directory, it will simply download the provisioning profiles to the current directory in which you are running the command.  The default directory for Xcode's provisioning profiles is `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/`.

Try running the sigh command as

`fastlane sigh -o "~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/"`

to output the profiles downloaded from the developer site to the standard Xcode location.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  That's what I get for doing it from memory.